# Firebase working with list data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

```
"groups": {

"techpioneers": {

      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",

      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
```

This kind of structure is found in firebase docs but I can't figure out how to do the "members" child. How to write the 'wildcard' username as the key and boolean as the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually just need to write the boolean value (or the username object) to the database. The needed child nodes are created, when you add the first child.

For example:

```
firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members' + username).set(true);
```

or

```
firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members').set({username: true});
```

Comment: I get the result i wanted using the first example! thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()`. Firebase works with URLs so you can access `members` as the example shows.

```
firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members').set({
    alovelace: true,
    ghopper: true,
    eclarke: true
});
```

**EDIT:**

You can set `alovelace` to current uid. First of all get the current user uid.

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid = '';
if (user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;
}
```

Then set it

```
var Obj = {};
Obj[uid] = true;
firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members/').set(Obj);
```

If you want to set more than one user inside members you can use `push()`:

```
var Obj = {};
Obj[uid] = true;
firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members/').push(Obj);
```

Check the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/save-data)

Comment: but what if i want to change the alovelace to the current uid? i tried this before but using firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members').set({
    uid : true   //uid is a variable of containing current uid value
});

Comment: that should do..
firebase.database().ref('groups/techpioneers/members/' + uid).set({
    uid: true
});
i think the name key should be changed to uid?

Comment: Check my edit @ShadyChan. In the example I'm setting the key with the value of the `uid`. If my answer helped you consider approving it.

Comment: If my answer helped you consider approving it. @ShadyChan